# Cannot access memory - gdb

Tags: c, gdb

Here is my disas code:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x00000000000006b0 <+0>:    push   %rbp
0x00000000000006b1 <+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x00000000000006b4 <+4>:    sub    $0x10,%rsp
0x00000000000006b8 <+8>:    movl   $0xa,-0xc(%rbp)
0x00000000000006bf <+15>:   lea    -0xc(%rbp),%rax
0x00000000000006c3 <+19>:   mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
0x00000000000006c7 <+23>:   lea    0x96(%rip),%rdi        # 0x764
0x00000000000006ce <+30>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x00000000000006d3 <+35>:   callq  0x560 <printf@plt>
0x00000000000006d8 <+40>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x00000000000006dd <+45>:   leaveq 
0x00000000000006de <+46>:   retq
```

when I set the breakpoint at 0x06b4 by  b *0x00000000000006b4 and run the code it is giving an error
`Starting program: /root/print.out 
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 4.
Cannot access memory at address 0x6b4`

but when I do it with  ***b 4*** and run the code ,it is working normal. so what am I doing wrong in the first case.

Comment: did you check the addresses when the breakpoints are working? do they match with the disassembly?

Comment: Yes, they are the same

Comment: Those addresses are extraordinarily low. Can you please edit your question to add a description of your operating system, compilation settings, gdb command line options, etc.?

Comment: those disassembled instruction offsets look to be before the code is 'relocated' by the linker.  
strongly suggest to always use labels that exist in the program (like function names and/or  labels you have placed in the source code and/or function name + offset

Answer (score 2):

> `Dump of assembler code for function main:
>   0x00000000000006b0 <+0>:    push   %rbp
>   0x00000000000006b1 <+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp`

You are looking at [position-independent executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) (a special kind of shared library). The code for `main` gets *relocated* to a different address when the executable starts running.

Because there is no code at `0x6b4` once the executable is relocated, GDB complains that it can't set a breakpoint there.

> but when I do it with b 4 and run the code ,it is working normal.

In this case, GDB understands that you want to set breakpoint on line 4, and inserts appropriate breakpoint *after* the executable has been relocated.

Use `info break` to see what the relocated address is.